# Unique hash-values across 2 different sql-tables

Tags: sql, database, security, hash, passwords

I want to store a **hashed password with a random salt**. The hash-value should be **unique across two different sql-tables**.

The salt consists of random characters and numbers and the slash is not allowed in the passwords and the logins.

To ensure the uniqueness I want to append a delimiter and the unique login.

Example (pseudo code):

```
 hash(salt + password + “/” + login)
```

The idea is to avoid searching two different tables for unique random salts.

Is it less secure if I build the stored hash this way?

Comment: Just using a hash function is not sufficient and just adding a salt does little to improve the security. Instead iIterate over an HMAC with a random salt for about a 100ms duration and save the salt with the hash. Use functions such as `PBKDF2`, `Rfc2898DeriveBytes`, `password_hash`, `Bcrypt` and similar functions. The point is to make the attacker spend a lot of time finding passwords by brute force.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds to me like you are not using the right type of "hash" function to "hash" your password, because if you were, then you wouldn't need to ask this question.

Ordinary hash functions such as the SHA family are not suitable for protecting passwords.  The problem is that they are too fast to compute, which means passwords can be brute forced.  For more information, read [this](https://www.troyhunt.com/our-password-hashing-has-no-clothes/).

What you should be using is a function like [bcrypt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bcrypt) (or if that is not available, at least use [pbkdf2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PBKDF2)) that takes as input both the salt and the password as separate parameters and outputs the "hash" you store in your database.

I will apologise on behalf of the cryptographic and security community for this confusing use of the word ["hash"](https://adamcaudill.com/2016/05/23/when-hashing-isnt-hashing/).  Unfortunately, it does not look like it will be fixed any time soon.

Comment: Thank you for the great link (https://www.troyhunt.com/our-password-hashing-has-no-clothes/), after reading (and understanding) the text, I will perhaps be back to clarify my question.